# unix timestamp: not getting the correct year value by dividing

Tags: date, time, timestamp

I'm attempting to extract years from the timestamp, as indicated below:

```
const int timestamp = 1499477613;
int hours = timestamp/3600;
int days = hours/24;
int years = days/356;
printf("years=%i\n", years);
```

However after executing the program, I get an output saying:

> years=48

Which is different from the expected value `2017`.

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

> Unix time (also known as POSIX time or epoch time) is a system for
>   describing instants in time, defined as the number of seconds that
>   have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC),
>   Thursday, 1 January 1970.

That result tells you that (approximately) 48 years has passed since that time. `1970 + 48 = 2018`.

The reason you don't get an accurate value is precision you lose in each calculation. You're using ints to encode something that may return a floating point. (And what I assume to be a typo: `days/356` should be `days/365`)

Comment: And there is approximately 365.2422 days if you account for leap years.